# How to pass data dynamically from activity to service?

Tags: android, android-intent

What I did:

1. startService in MainActivity's `onCreate()`.
2. implement button `onBindServiceClicked(View v)` in MainActivity. So when the button is clicked, an intent with data will be sent to the service.

However, I found this only work once. When I clicked the button the second time, it seems the onBind() was not invoked.

Do I need to call something like `unbindService`, so that the `onBind()` will be invoked many times?

Comment: You just want to sent an intent to the service and no other communication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep sending data via Intent, you should use `Activity.startService(intent)` instead. Each time your service will have it's `onStartCommand()` callback invoked.